# How to move the character in a certain way?

Tags: unity-game-engine

There is a way. The character starts at the midpoint. Then it should move to the right, if `HorizontalAxis > 0` and to the left, if `< 0`. I have did something like this -

**Way:**

[image: way image]

```
public Transform[] PatrolPoints;
public Transform Way;
public int CurrentPoint;
public int NeedPoint;

if (transform.position == PatrolPoints[CurrentPoint].position && CurrentPoint < PatrolPoints.Length-1) 
{
    //PatrolPoints[CurrentPoint];
    NeedPoint = CurrentPoint + 1;
}       
else if(transform.position == PatrolPoints[NeedPoint].position && CurrentPoint != PatrolPoints.Length - 1)
{
    CurrentPoint++;
}
else if(transform.position == PatrolPoints[PatrolPoints.Length - 1].position)
{
    NeedPoint--;
}
if (CurrentPoint != PatrolPoints.Length - 1 && moveAxis > 0)
{
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, PatrolPoints[NeedPoint].position, moveAxis * moveRate * Time.deltaTime);
    //An error occurs here
}
    else if(CurrentPoint > 0 && moveAxis < 0)
{
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, PatrolPoints[NeedPoint - 1].position, -moveAxis * moveRate * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Length of the array - 3 elements.
From the middle point to the right, the character normally goes both left and right, but as soon as I get to the last point, an error occurs -

> Array index is out of range

During the error variables are:

NeedPoint: -1;

CurrnetPoint: 2;

And from the middle to the left point the character does not go at all.

Comment: it would be nice if you specified: 1. in which line the error occurs 2. what is the value of each variable in that line 3. the length of the array

Comment: @Bijan I'm sorry. Updated the question.

Comment: shouldn't it be [NeedPoint + 1] at the line with the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is the solution for:

> The character starts at the midpoint. Then it should move to the
>   right, if HorizontalAxis > 0 and to the left, if < 0.

i assumed that "move to the right" means increasing the index in array and "move to the left" means decreasing the index in array

```
public Transform[] PatrolPoints;
public int NextPointOnLeft = 0; // because player starts at 1
public int NextPointOnRight = 2; // because player starts at 1

if (HorizontalAxis < 0)
{
    if (transform.position == PatrolPoints[NextPointOnLeft].position)
    {
        if(NextPointOnLeft > 0)
        {
            --NextPointOnLeft;
        }
        // EDIT: NextPointOnRight = NextPointOnLeft + 1;
    }
    // EDIT:
    NextPointOnRight = NextPointOnLeft + 1;
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, PatrolPoints[NextPointOnLeft].position, moveRate * Time.deltaTime);
}
if (HorizontalAxis > 0)
{
    if (transform.position == PatrolPoints[NextPointOnRight].position)
    {
        if(NextPointOnRight < PatrolPoints.Length-1)
        {
            ++NextPointOnRight;
        }
        // EDIT: NextPointOnLeft = NextPointOnRight - 1;
    }
    // EDIT:
    NextPointOnLeft = NextPointOnRight - 1;
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, PatrolPoints[NextPointOnRight].position, moveRate * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

if you need a different solution, please specify what you need

Comment: Thanks. It works. But while the character is between the first and second point, he can go to zero bypassing the first and when the distance between the zero point and the first one can reach the second, the first one. I need that the character go only along the line. https://imgur.com/a/nDlACXE